# No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_constraintBottom' in package

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout, android-studio-2.3

I'm trying to build a simple android app in **Android Studio 2.3.2**, but I'm getting the following error for component I add to the app: "**No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_constraintBottom' in package 'com...**"

I researched this problem and found that some people are getting a similar error.  However, the answers are suggesting to add "compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'" to the gradle.build file.  When I looked there, the line is already in place.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/main_menu"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.nmeneses.scorekeeper.MainMenu"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main_menu">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="128dp"
    android:layout_height="79dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="39dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="Teams"
    android:textSize="23dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.066"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  If you need more info, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK there is no attribute `layout_constraintBottom` in `ConstraintLayout`. There is `layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf` and `layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf`.

I suggest that you use the following line instead:

```
 app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
```